# Steam won't start on Arch Linux - possibly libGL error (nvidia)

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, libraries, graphics, steam

Whenever I try to launch Steam I get the "Steam upgrading" loading screen for a split second and then every Steam process dies.

When I run steam, steam-runtime or steam-native in terminal I get following output (text in double curly brackets are my comments):

```
/home/USER/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Zeile 154: VERSION_ID ist nicht gesetzt. {{line154: VERSION_ID not set.}}
/home/USER/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Zeile 154: VERSION_ID ist nicht gesetzt. {{line154: VERSION_ID not set.}}
Running Steam on arch  64-bit
/home/USER/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Zeile 154: VERSION_ID ist nicht gesetzt. {{line154: VERSION_ID not set.}}
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)

{{Steam upgrade window pops up}}

(steam:1581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:37:59.515: Im Modulpfad »adwaita« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden, {{No theme engine found in module path »adwaita«}}
/usr/share/themes/Matcha-dark-sea/gtk-2.0/main.rc:1102: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
/usr/share/themes/Matcha-dark-sea/gtk-2.0/apps.rc:91: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
crash_20180422113758_1.dmp[1611]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20180422113758_1.dmp
/home/USER/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Zeile 927:  1581 Speicherzugriffsfehler  (Speicherabzug geschrieben) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@" {{1581 memory access error (wrote dump) …}}
crash_20180422113758_1.dmp[1611]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20180422113758_1.dmp[1611]: response: CrashID=bp-096dbe58-03c4-4dbb-8045-fcefa2180422
crash_20180422113758_1.dmp[1611]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20180422113758_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-096dbe58-03c4-4dbb-8045-fcefa2180422''
```

Running find /usr -iname "*libGL.so*" -exec ls -l -- {} + gives me this output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14  9. Nov 10:02 /usr/lib32/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14  9. Nov 10:02 /usr/lib32/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 386364  9. Nov 10:02 /usr/lib32/libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14  9. Nov 09:44 /usr/lib/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14  9. Nov 09:44 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 562944  9. Nov 09:44 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14  9. Nov 10:02 /usr/lib32/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.0
```

lspci output about my graphics card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem by installing the lib32-nvidia-utils package.